# I'd like to hide a Button in iOS 5.x but not in iOS 6.x

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have my app here, which supports iOS 5.1 and newer. However, I'd like to hide the camera button when lower than iOS 6.x. How can I do this? Here is how I add the Camerabutton:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[ATWebViewController class]]) {
    NSURL *url = nil;
    if (viewController.tabBarItem.tag == 0) {
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://----.de"];
    }
    else if (viewController.tabBarItem.tag == 1) {
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://----.de"];
    }
```

//        if viewController.tabBarItem.tag==0 
        ATWebViewController *webViewController = [[ATWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil URL:url ];

```
    UINavigationController *navigationBarController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:webViewController];

    navigationBarController.navigationBar.tintColor = ATNavigationBarTintColor;

    if (viewController.tabBarItem.tag == 0) {

    webViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissWebView)];
    webViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:self action:@selector(TakePhoto)];
        }

     else if (viewController.tabBarItem.tag == 1) {

    webViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissWebView)];
         }

    navigationBarController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    [self presentModalViewController:navigationBarController animated:YES];
    return NO;
}
return YES;
```

}

Comment: Why do you wish to do this? Is there some 6.x API you need for the camera?

Comment: We just implement the camera for a market, which is a webView. Uploading pictures in a webView is only supported in iOS 6. Therefore the button makes no sense in iOS 5.1.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally it is best to check for a specific feature by checking for the existence of a class or method. But in this case there is no suitable API check against `UIWebView`.

One solution would be to do:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] hasPrefix:@"5"]) {
    // iOS 5.x
} else {
    // not iOS 5.x
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much... I knew I had to check the iOS Version, but tried with the availability of SLComposeViewOfTypeFacebook... This one is far better... :)